# TypeScript: How to type an object with dynamic keys and dynamic depth

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function that generates an object by a given configuration structure. The key is user defined. The value can be a string, a number, a boolean or an object with more key value pairs or another object. Here is an example:

```
    {
  itemKeyLevel1: 'localized item level 1',
  groupKeyLevel2: {
    itemKeyLevel2: 'localized item level 2',
    groupKeyLevel3: { itemKeyLevel3: 1337, groupKeyLevel4: { itemKeyLevel41: 1337, itemKeyLevel42: 13.37 } },
    itemKeyLevel3: 1337,
    groupKeyLevel4: { itemKeyLevel41: 1337, itemKeyLevel42: 13.37 },
    groupKeyLevel3Headline: { itemKeyLevel3: 1337 }
  },
  itemKeyLevel2: 'localized item level 2',
  groupKeyLevel3: {
    itemKeyLevel3: 1337,
    groupKeyLevel4: { itemKeyLevel41: 1337, itemKeyLevel42: 13.37 }
  },
  itemKeyLevel3: 1337,
  groupKeyLevel4: { itemKeyLevel41: 1337, itemKeyLevel42: 13.37 },
  groupKeyLevel3Headline: { itemKeyLevel3: 1337 }
}
```

I need help by type this structure in TypeScript. Actually i am using:

```
type GetValueObjectFromFormGroupReturn = Record<string, string | number | boolean> | Record<string, any>;
```

But i want to get rid of that any.

Comment: It's basically `any`, isn't it…?

Comment: I tried it like Yoshi. But if i want to access the object with object.key1.key2 TypeScript has an error that the key1 or key2 does not exist at this type.

Comment: If the user is providing this in "javascript land" then, like @deceze said, `any` is the correct type.

If this is something that developers are consuming you can make the type generic:

`type GetValueObjectFromFormGroupReturn<T> = Record<string, string | number | boolean> | Record<string, T>;`

Comment: Thank you @shabs. But what type should "T" then be? If I make it like you suggest, TypeScript has an error "Generic type 'GetValueObjectFromFormGroupReturn' requires 1 type argument(s).".

Comment: Yes, every use of `GetValueObjectFromFormGroupReturn` would now need to be `GetValueObjectFromFormGroupReturn<SomeType>`. You can learn more about generics here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html

Comment: @shabs But what type should i use. I need type "GetValueObjectFromFormGroupReturn" again because I want to have child object with the same types possible.